# Trouble in testing with invalid field

Tags: testing, salesforce, apex

```
public with sharing class SobjectByParams {
    public SObject createSObject(String sObjectName, Map<String, String> fields) {

        String invalidSObjectError = System.Label.invalid_Sobject_Name;
        String invalidFieldError = System.Label.Invalid_Sobject_Field;

        SObject newObject;
        try {
            newObject = (SObject) Type.forName(sObjectName).newInstance();
        } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
            throw new InvalidTypeNameException(invalidSObjectError);
        }

        for (String field : fields.keySet()) {
            try {
                newObject.put(field, fields.get(field));
            } catch (SObjectException ex) {
                throw new InvalidTypeNameException(invalidFieldError);
            }
        }

        insert newObject;
        return newObject;
    }

    public class InvalidTypeNameException extends Exception {
    }
}


@IsTest
public with sharing class SobjectByParamsTest {

    SobjectByParams sobjectByParams;

    private static final String TestName = 'TestName';
    private static final String BCity = 'Lviv';
    private static final String LastName = 'Kapo';
    private static final String Email = 'email';

    @IsTest
    static void createSObject() {
        SobjectByParams sobjectByParams = new SobjectByParams();
        Map<String, String> fields = new Map<String, String>();
        fields.put('BillingCity', BCity);
        Test.startTest();
        SObject result = sobjectByParams.createSObject(TestName, fields);
        Test.stopTest();
        System.assertEquals(BCity, result.get(BCity));
    }
}
```

SobjectByParams.InvalidTypeNameException: invalidSobjectNameError - PROBLEM

TEST WORKING on 53.33% but I need min 80%

I don`t know how to fix my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't `TestName` be a sObject name like `Contact`? Does this code work when you run it normally, does it insert anything or throw? Check/fix that and then you probably need a negative test too.

Make second test method

```
@isTest
static void testPassingBadData() {
    SobjectByParams sobjectByParams = new SobjectByParams();
    Map<String, String> fields = new Map<String, String>();
    fields.put('BillingCity', BCity);
    try{
        sobjectByParams.createSObject('NoSuchObjectInTheSystem', fields);
        System.assert(false, 'This should have failed and thrown exception');
    } catch(Exception e){
        System.assert(e.getMessage().contains(Label.Invalid_Sobject_Field));
    }
}
```